# SQL - FILTER condition in JOIN clause

Tags: sql

I am inserting data to an already existing `TableA` and the following query is a part of a stored procedure. This part of the query inserts values into some columns of `TableA`. The stored procedure is very lengthy which has several insert statements to fill out the different columns in `TableA`.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ID, Event, Date, Amount, Status_, Country)
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Event, Date, Amount, c.Status, b.Country 
     FROM TableA1 a
     JOIN TableB1 b ON b.employeeID = a.ID
     JOIN TableC1 c ON c.Status = ‘Active’)
```

Usually, a join condition consists of two columns, for example `(a.Status_ = c.Status)`. But here, it's replaced with a filter condition `(JOIN TableC1 c ON c.Status = ‘Active’)`.

The select query alone executes well and returns results. I'm trying to understand the effect made by this filter condition.

Can you explain, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID, Event, Date, Amount, c.Status, b.Country 
FROM
(
    TableA1 a
  INNER JOIN
    TableB1 b
      ON b.employeeID = a.ID
)
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM TableC1 WHERE Status = 'Active'
)
  c
```

In effect, the `INNER JOIN` is resolved, and then ***each*** row from that is joined to ***every*** row from `TableC1 WHERE Status = 'Active'`

For example

TableA1

| ID | Event | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | e1 | 2022-01-01 | 11 |
| 2 | e2 | 2022-02-02 | 22 |

TableB1

| EmployeeID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 |
| 2 | c2 |

TableC1

| some_id | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sleeping |
| 2 | Active |
| 3 | Active |
| 4 | Sleeping |

Would yield...

| ID | Event | Date | Amount | Country | Status | (some_id, added by me) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | e1 | 2022-01-01 | 11 | c1 | Active | 2 |
| 1 | e1 | 2022-01-01 | 11 | c1 | Active | 3 |
| 2 | e2 | 2022-02-02 | 22 | c2 | Active | 2 |
| 2 | e2 | 2022-02-02 | 22 | c2 | Active | 3 |

You ***probably*** should have...

```
INNER JOIN
 TableC1 c
   ON  c.some_id = b.some_other_id
   AND c.Status  = 'Active'
```

Comment: The OP wrote that the query executes well. So he probably does not need the `AND` clause.

Comment: @user14063792468 If you read what the query Does, it's unlikely to be correct or complete. It filters Status to be 'Active', and then selects only the Status column. May as well just select a literal 'Active' rather than use a join. Also, it will duplicate the rows in a meaningless way. As the OP didn't know what it was doing, it is fair to show alternative patterns for the Op to work out what they need for themselves.

Comment: The last join is meaningless in terms of sane data query. Yes. But OP did not follow the usual way of posting a `database` question. No input data, no expected output. You should have pointed to that. SO not a web site to do his homework.